# What prevents `nobody` user from listing a directory that it owns?

Tags: linux, permissions, linux-networking

This is all in an LXC container and I'm logged in as `nobody` user.

```
$ whoami
nobody
$ ls /share
ls: cannot open directory '/share': Permission denied
$ ls -lha / | grep share
drwxrws---    9 nobody       4000  183 Mar 21 18:30 share
```

Now, it appears that the `nobody` user cannot list a directory it owns.

This `/share` is mounted from a NAS:

```
$ mount -l | grep share
a_nas:/share/a_nas/my_storage on /share type nfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,nodiratime,vers=3,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=SOME.IP,mountvers=3,mountport=20048,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=SOME.IP)
```

Importantly, I have no access to the NAS server.

Comment: What are the export options on the server? Is kerberos authentication used on this export? (this is unlikely) Are there any ip address restrictions on the nfs share? Is the user and group id for `nobody` user the same on both client and server? Is there a firewall which allows mountd but blocks nfs?

Comment: @Tomek Unfortunately, I have no access to the NAS server. I've updated my question.

Comment: `showmount -e <a_nas>` may be of some help here (usually it shows ip/netgroup restrictions). Can you cd to this directory?

Comment: And can you possibly check if it works outside container?